# context variable php

Tags: php, class, variables, global-variables

I'm trying to create a global context variable in one of my libraries, but can't seem to figure out how to make the variable stick. Below is a sample of my code:

```
class test{
    function tester(){
        echo context::getContext();
        echo '<br />';
        context::setContext(2);
        echo context::getContext();
        echo '<br />';
        new test2();
    }
}
class test2{
    public function __construct(){
        echo context::getContext();
    }
}
class context{
    protected static $contextNum = 0;
    public function getContext(){
        return isset($this->contextNum) ? $this->contextNum : 0;
    }
    public function setContext($num){
        $this->contextNum = $num;
    }
}
```

This ends up echoing:

```
0
2
0
```

How can I make it so that it echoes out?

```
0
2
2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$this->contextNum = $num;
// and
return isset($this->contextNum) ? $this->contextNum : 0;
```

to

```
self::$contextNum = $num;
// and
return isset(self::$contextNum) ? self::$contextNum : 0;
```

Use static modifiers for methods `setContext()` and `getContext()`

Also I would advise you to add `throw new Exception('Can\'t create instance of this class')` to `__construct()` method of `context`.

Comment: I actually have a construct for the context class, it just wasn't pertinent in this example hence I didn't include it. Would there be a reason to not allow the instanciation of a contextual class?

Comment: Oh, I though you want, make it all static... then ignore advise about set static modifiers to methods, and about construct...

Comment: would there be any benefit to making the methods static in this case considering that the variable itself is static?

Comment: If you need to use instances of class `context`, and call this method from there - you shouldn't place static, otherwise, in order to restrict access by only static (it's more "gracefully") and to show that methods are modifying static props you should place static keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class context(){
    protected static $contextNum = 0;
    public function getContext(){
        return isset(self::$contextNum) ? self::$contextNum : 0;
    }
    public function setContext($num){
        self::$contextNum = $num;
    }
}
```

`$this->contextNum` is used to access `contextNum` as an instance variable (i.e. one that exists on an instance of the class `context`), while `self::$contextNum` is used to access it as a static variable.